# Is there a way to manage who can install the Google Drive desktop client?

Tags: google-drive

As we have a number of users traveling overseas we want to be able to do all of the following or some of the following. How can we manage this using the Google Apps dashboard? If some of these are not administrable via the dashboard, what options do we have available?

1. Choose the users that can install the client on their desktop
2. Define the PCs that are allowed to have the client installed so that no rogue devices can install the application